# Create image grid using json html and js

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following instruction in html with which I show some images, this I do with a json previously, I want somehow to show the images in the form of a grid with two rows of 8 columns or something similar, but I have not been able to iterate inside the for loop something like a table or column.

could someone give me some help.
Regards.

```
<pre>
   var json2 = json;
   var jnombre = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < json2.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("iterar").innerHTML += `
</pre>                    
<section class="products-list">
   <div class="product-item"  data-id="${json2[i].id}" data-category="${json2[i].categoria}">
      <img alt="" src="${json2[i].imagen}"/>
      <a href="${json2[i].enlace}"></a>
      <center style="text-align: center;">
         <a class="btn btn-outline-warning " href="${json2[i].enlace}">${json2[i].nombre}
         </a>
      </center>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Corrected formatting of code to make it more readable and corrected a little gramer to make the question a little more understandable

Comment: Use [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to define columns of your grid.